# Node JS Callback vs Queues

Tags: node.js, express

In an example where an e-commerce website successfully takes a request for an order, a response is sent indicating the Order Number. After this, an email is sent to the customer with the order information. The email doesn't have to be instantaneous and can go after a little bit of time

I am using Node JS (Express)

This being the case, which is better?
1) Send response. Execute code to send email
2) Enqueue to some Queue (like on AWS) and process it later

While I know that the second method is good, would the first one make the user to continue to wait for response? What if the email sending code was in some kind of a callback? Or are  they two different ways of achieving the same thing?

Comment: Callbacks don't necessarily imply asynchronous execution, so yes, if sending the email is synchronous and potentially time expensive try and find a way to decouple it from the HTTP request-reaponse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are pretty much the same thing. If you use a call back that runs asynchronously the user wouldn't have to wait.

The enqueuing is only worth while if there are some checks that need to be done before confirming the order, say checking with the payment system to identify if the payment details are correct.

Since sending an email is a task the server can handle without calling any external APIs(payment check etc.), if that's all that's required better to handle by a callback instead of a queue.